# Cannot capture output of git branch command into bash variable

Tags: bash, git

Very wierd. If I run this command interactively, I see the expected result:

```
    git branch --contains c46b341b72509a02ee1c1a489a7f9b37d477c4f5
    * v2Tunnel
```

But if I try to capture this in a variable, what gets captured is the names of some (but not all) files in the current folder, followed by the expected branch name (v2Tunnel is not a file in my directory)

```
    CCC=$(git branch --contains c46b341b72509a02ee1c1a489a7f9b37d477c4f5)
    # OR
    CCC=`git branch --contains c46b341b72509a02ee1c1a489a7f9b37d477c4f5`

    echo $CCC
    IWiNS README.md cicommit citest v2Tunnel
```

Other git commands to not have this result:

```
    CCC=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
    echo $CCC
    v2Tunnel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You captured `* v2Tunnel` in `CCC` so when you do `echo $CCC` the shell interprets that `*` and lists local files.

To prevent shell to interpret `*` use double quotes:

```
echo "$CCC"
```